# why simple grammar rule in bison not working?

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am learning flex & bison and I am stuck here and cannot figure out how such a simple grammar rule does not work as I expected, below is the lexer code:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include "zparser.tab.h"

%}

%%

[\t\n ]+        //ignore white space

FROM|from           { return FROM;   }
select|SELECT       { return SELECT; }
update|UPDATE       { return UPDATE; }
insert|INSERT       { return INSERT; }
delete|DELETE       { return DELETE; }
[a-zA-Z].*          { return IDENTIFIER; }
\*                  { return STAR;   }

%%
```

And below is the parser code:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

extern int yyerror(const char* str);
extern int yylex();


%}

%%

%token SELECT UPDATE INSERT DELETE STAR IDENTIFIER FROM;


ZQL     : SELECT STAR FROM  IDENTIFIER { cout<<"Done"<<endl; return 0;}
        ;

%%
```

Can any one tell me why it shows error if I try to put "select * from something"

Comment: Careful of tagging.  The Flex tag is used for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.  The Flex-lexer tag is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: Shows what error, at what token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[a-zA-Z].*          { return IDENTIFIER; }`

The problem is here. It allows any junk to follow an initial alpha character and be returned as `IDENTIFIER,` including in this case the entire rest of the line after the initial ''s.

It should be:

```
[a-zA-Z]+          { return IDENTIFIER; }
```

or possibly

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*          { return IDENTIFIER; }
```

or whatever else you want to allow to follow an initial alpha character in your identifiers.

Comment: Can you help me write a rule to match any identifier not belonging to one of the key words (I may want to add more keywords later)

Comment: @smit I have just done *exactly that* in my answer. What a ridiculous request.

Answer (score 2):

`[a-zA-Z].*` will match an alphabetic character followed by any number of arbitrary characters except newline. In other words, it will match from an alphabetic character to the end of the line.

Since flex always accepts the longest match, the line `select * from ...` will appear to have only one token, `IDENTIFIER`, and that is a syntax error.

Comment: I got it, but I still want to ask is it the only criteria for matching, I mean the longest match rule? Actually what I want to do is write a pattern that will match any identifier starting with alphabet but not one of the keywords that I already written rules for above.

Comment: @smit: you need to be more precise. An identifier cannot consist of any characters whatsoever; normally, it must be a letter followed by a series of letters or digits, with possibly some other valid characters (like `_` or `$`). So, for example, `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` (just letters and numbers). To avoid clashing with keywords, you need to put keywords first, because flex chooses the first match from the longest matches (that is, first it finds the longest match, and then selects the first pattern which matches that.)

Comment: I did not actually tried it but what you put here i.e. [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* will it not match with keywords like SELECT or UPDATE I mean they too start with an alpha followed by some character or number...that is confusing me.

Comment: @smit: yes, it will match. In that case, there will be two rules which match, and flex will choose the *first* one. As I said, flex first figures out which rule(s) have the longest possible match, and then selects the first such rule if there are more than one. So you need to put the keyword rules first in your file, as you have done.